# Cannot find context with specified id in Java - Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click an element inside a `iframe`

code trial :

```
driver.switchTo().frame("payment_page");
WebElement cardType = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"AMEX-paymenttype\"]")));
cardType.click();
```

Error Msg:
org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //*[@id="AMEX-paymenttype"])

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? Update the question with the error stack trace

Comment: relevant HTML and error trace ?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //*[@id="AMEX-paymenttype"])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *Best Practices* before you switch to any *frame* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *frame* to be available and switch to it. Once you have switched to the desired *frame* further as you are invoking `click()` method so instead of using the *ExpectedConditions* method *visibilityOfElementLocated* you need to use [**`elementToBeClickable`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("payment_page")));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"AMEX-paymenttype\"]"))).click();
```

Comment: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //*[@id=\"AMEX-paymenttype\"])
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Cannot find context with specified id"}
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139)                                                        I am using TestNG. weird it is working on a Java class but not on TESTNG Class.

Comment: `unhandled inspector error` indicates the _xpath_ you have identified as `//*[@id=\"AMEX-paymenttype\"]` is incorrect. Either you use a correct _xpath_ or provide the relevant _HTML_

Comment: when I run my class as java application the element is clickable, but in TestNG I encountered this error.